# How to force maven to execute next goals after tests failures

Tags: java, maven, testing, pom.xml

I'm running tests on a project using the surefire plugin and then need to generate a report using the "site" goal, even if there are failed tests.

The thing is that by default surefire forces the build to fail in a case of failed tests and no further goals are executed. 
So that I set the following configuration to surefire:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${surefire.version}</version>
        <configuration>
            <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
        </configuration>
</plugin>
```

This works well and the "site" goal is always executed, but in such a case the status of the build is always "Success" so that I can't set up emails notification.

Is there a proper way to execute the next goals after a "test" goal without ignoring the failures in the surefire plugin?

Comment: you can always run without the tests.

Comment: Use the `failsafe` plugin instead of `surefire`. It is the same plugin except the failure can be delayed. You verify the success or fail the build by calling failsafe's `verify` goal. This is what Maven does by default for integration tests. They normally need cleanup, so Maven delays the build failure until a later step.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could use:

- `-DskipTests=true` to skip test execution entirely
- `-Dmaven.test.failure.ignore=true` to ignore test failures
- `--fail-at-end` to let the build continue **after** the test phase and only fail (if there are test failures) when the entire build cycle is complete

Given this statement ...

> This works well and the "site" goal is always executed, but in such a case the status of the build is always "Success" so that I can't set up emails notification.

... I think you want to use `--fail-at-end`. According to the docs its behaviour is:

> **--fail-at-end** - if a particular module build fails, continue the rest of the reactor and report all failed modules at the end instead

Comment: `--fail-at-end` was exactly what I needed.

Comment: it seems `--fail-at-end` won't execute next phase for the module with failures?

Answer (score 0):

> I'm running tests on a project using the surefire plugin and then need to generate a report using the "site" goal, even if there are failed tests.

If I understand your question right, what you do is equivalent to simply running `mvn site` (or `mvn site:stage`) goal! It will generate the site after running the tests and (if configured so) include a report of which failed and which didn't. It will not fail as you didn't request to 'test the project' but to 'build the site of the project with test results' which it succeed to do.

> ... the status of the build is always "Success" so that I can't set up emails notification.

Given your description, I assume sending notifications is based on build status and notifications have a link to the generated site. If that is the case there are 3 options I can think of that may give you what you want:

- change notifications to be triggered by the output of surefire plugin (typically in `${basedir}/target/surefire-reports`) rather then the build status. Then you can simply run `mvn site`
- somehow publish/share surefire output files (transform them if needed) and make notifications point to them instead of pointing to the site. Then you can simply run `mvn test`
- run `mvn site test` which will generate the site first (running tests and ignoring failures to build reports) and then run tests (again) to fail your build